# react-native textinput securetextentry star instead of dots

Tags: react-native, textinput

Is there a way to change the style of textInput in react-native when secureTextEntry is true. I want to display stars(*) instead of dots for hidden texts.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own TextInput, a component that renders a textInput, but changes the value to *, based on the length of the input, that you can store on state

```
<SecureInput value = {this.state} onTextChange = {callbackToUpdateState}/>
```

and on SecureInput, you can `<TextInput/>` with the value being a star for each char of the value

Comment: that would require maintaining two values, original and star, then put new characters to original value char by char and then replace with star. It would be unnecessary work. I thought, maybe RN provides a way to customise it.

Comment: Kind of good answer, but RN should need to provide better solution via there API